# How to install DVB-T2 protocol source on Ubuntu

Tags: totem, dvb-t

How to install DVB-T2 protocol source for totem or for Parole media player on Ubuntu ??

Comment: You need DVB-T2 tuner hardware and drivers. There's no "protocol" to install.

Comment: i have DVB-T2 tuner and drivers installed. I-ts running OK with VLC player, but not running with other players.  Totem and Parole need DVB-T2 protocol source plugins. Other player MeTv or kaffeine not running this content. http://imgur.com/a/cU5Iy

Comment: see this videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXxubfweafQ

Comment: and this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efnxrm50cGE

Comment: Extra codecs are available by installing the package *ubuntu-restricted-extras* (change the name to Xubuntu or Lubuntu if you're using any of this flavors; keep "Ubuntu" as such otherwise).

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extras already installed...

Comment: If so there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: Do any of these help: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/DVBDaemon/UserGuide (English), https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Totem/DVB/ (German)? If you manage to solve your issue, please answer your own question for the benefit of future readers. :-)